# How to test ssh tunelling?

Tags: ssh, ssh-tunnel

Let's say I create a reverse ssh tunnel, with the following command.

```
ssh -R 8080:localhost:11111 user@remote
```

I can test that the tunnel is open on the remote with nc command

```
nc -v 127.0.0.1 8080
localhost.localdomain [127.0.0.1] 8080 (http-alt) open
```

However I have no idea how I could test that the remote can indeed communicate with the client trough the tunnel, how could I do that ?

Comment: You want to create that tunnel to do something. Why don't you just try this something and see if it works?

Comment: Of course, but that something is quite complex and can have multiple points of failure. I first need to make sure the tunnel is working correctly with the simplest test possible.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to test a ssh tunnel is with the telnet command and with a python http server.

For reverse connection, this would be the following.
On the local, install python3 and ssh, then.

1. Run a python http server in a terminal (on port 8000 by default)

   `python -m http.server`
2. Create your ssh tunnel

   `ssh -R 8080:localhost:8000 user@remote`

On The remote, connect to it trough telnet

```
>telnet localhost 8080
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
```

You can even connect to it with a browser, but it not as simple as telnet.